# How is the digital certificate sent alongside digital signatures?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature, asymmetric

Most tutorials on the net only mention sending the digital signature attached to the document, but without the digital signature certificate, it'll be impossible for receivers to verify the signature. I'm assuming that the digital certificate is somehow sent alongside the signature but I can't seem to find any source mentioning that.

Comment: The cert is part of the signature. The cert has the key used to check the hash.

Comment: @schroeder Can you tell me which part of the signature has the certificate? Any article explaining the same? I assume the certificate will be *attached* to the signature, not exactly *part* of it

Comment: The cert (or chain) is often sent with the signature, but that isn't the only way a receiver or verifier (which may be different) can get it. The original X.500 concept was for a worldwide realtime directory, and although that flopped some environments still use LDAP, basically a cut-down version.  PGP mostly uses on-demand fetching from public keyservers, although recently vandalism has degraded this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most externally signed files (such as authenticode, PDF, etc.) use embedded signed PKCS#7 container that contains signature and related data, such as signing certificate, chain, counter signatures (signed timestamps). Here is a top-level ASN.1 definition of signed PKCS#7 ([RFC 2315](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315)):

```
SignedData ::= SEQUENCE {
    version Version,
    digestAlgorithms DigestAlgorithmIdentifiers,
    contentInfo ContentInfo,
    certificates
       [0] IMPLICIT ExtendedCertificatesAndCertificates
         OPTIONAL,
    crls
      [1] IMPLICIT CertificateRevocationLists OPTIONAL,
    signerInfos SignerInfos }
```

Signature itself and (optional) counter signatures sit in `signerInfos` field and related certificates sit in `certificates` field.

Digital signature without public signing certificate is useless, because in this case you don't have any means to validate the signature. Thus, as a rule, public signing certificates are ALWAYS attached to signature.

Comment: Several file formats use PKCS7 or its successor CMS, but others use PGP, xmldsig, or JWS, all of which are different. Comms protocols like TLS, SSH (with OpenSSH extension) and IPsec (optionally) are different again.

Answer (score 1):

For encrypted email, there's a few options. S/MIME (which uses the same sort of X.509 certificates used for TLS, etc.) clients typically attach the certificate to the signed message (for example, in Microsoft Outlook, this is the default behavior but it can be toggled off).

For PGP / GPG (in any of its various forms), people sometimes attach their public key to the message - some clients will offer to do this automatically - but recipients can also attempt to retrieve the user's public key from a keyserver or similar. Alternatively, one can simply avoid sending signed mail (or treat all signatures on received mail as untrusted) unless it is to / from a person you have met personally and exchanged public keys with. Scaling out the distribution of trusted keys has long been a problem for PGP.